# Regex for matching different parts of a domain

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk, regex-group, capture-group

I am attempting to split up domains into different categories (Subdomain, Domain, TLD) and am having trouble..

I can't figure out a way to match any number of subdomains and not overtake my domain or TLD mathcing. I am using PCRE regex.

**Current regex:**

```
\s(?:(?<subdomain>[a-z0-9\-]*){0,1}\.){0,3}(?<domain>(?>([a-z0-9\-]+)))\.(?<tld>[a-z\.]{2,6})\s
```

**Data set:**

```
 apple.orange.banana.clevername.co.uk 
 strawberry.apple.orange.banana.clevername.co.uk 
 tangerine.com.au
 simple.com
```

**Note:** There are spaces before and after the domains and they will always be lower case.

**An example of how this data would match:**

> apple.orange.banana.clevername.co.uk
>
> subdomain: apple.orange.banana
> domain: google
> tld: co.uk

If I add another fruit to the subdomain(strawberry.apple.orange.banana.clevername.co.uk), the match will fail.  If I modify the {0,3} for the subdomain regex to a higher number or an unlimited number of matches, it gets too greedy and I no longer end up with a correct match for a domain/tld. Example of this:

**Modified regex:**

```
\s(?:(?<subdomain>[a-z0-9\-]*){0,1}\.){0,5}(?<domain>(?>([a-z0-9\-]+)))\.(?<tld>[a-z\.]{2,6})\s
```

**Resulting match with new regex:**

> strawberry.apple.orange.banana.clevername.co.uk
>
> subdomain: strawberry.apple.orange.banana.clevername
> domain:
> tld: co.uk

I'm sure the regex isn't the most efficient either so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it for you:

`\s((?<subdomain>[a-z0-9\.\-]*)\.)?(?<domain>[a-z0-9\-]{3,}(?=\.[a-z\.]{3,6}))\.(?<tld>[a-z\.]{3,6})\s`

Tested this in Splunk and it works with your test data set.

Do note that this won't work for very short domains like `bit.ly` because there is no way to tell the domain from the subdomain without doing a lookup of the TLD.

For example, compare `something.bit.ly` and `clevername.com.au`. Without outside information, there is no way to tell that `bit` and `clevername` are the domains.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same problem. So I took Syon's regex and modified it a bit. This is the result:

`\s(?:(?<subdomain>[a-z0-9\.\-]*)\.)?(?<domain>(?!com)[a-z0-9\-]{3,}(?=\.[a-z\.]{2,}))\.(?:(?<tld>[a-z\.]{2,})$)\s`

It works on the whole test data set (I trimmed the spaces though), as well as short domains like `bit.ly`. Also works for new top level domains like `.cancerresearch`. See result:
https://regex101.com/r/nX6yQ7/4

Note: The regex specifically states that the `domain` can't be `com`, this needs to be updated if other `{3 characters}.xyz` `tlds` need to be supported

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the longest suffix of the domain which is still listed in the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org). After that, splitting the string should be easy.

Note that the list also considers domains of web hosters a public suffix. For example, in `example.blogspot.com` the public suffix is considered to be `blogspot.com`, not `com`. Also the list has to be parsed carefully as it contains comments and exceptions.